# add different data-attribute to elements, creating by js

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

Please, help. How can I set  the different data attribute to the elements, which creating by js with using forEach?

```
const buttons = ['%', 'C', 'DEL', '÷', '1', '2', '3', '*', '4', '5', '6', '+', '7', '8', '9', '-', '.', '0', '='];
buttons.forEach(button => {
    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.innerHTML = button;
    fragment.appendChild(btn);
});
```

in the end I should get

```
<button data-all-clear class="span-two">AC</button>
    <button data-delete>DEL</button>
    <button data-operation>÷</button>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
```

How can it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check **ASCII** character of each element in an array using **'charCodeAt'** method.
Please check working example below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Ascii</title>
    
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            const buttons = ['%', 'C', 'DEL', '÷', '1', '2', '3', '*', '4', '5', '6', '+', '7', '8', '9', '-', '.', '0', '='];
            const fragment = document.getElementById('fragment');
            buttons.forEach(button => {
                const btn = document.createElement('button');
                const charCode = button.charCodeAt();
                if (charCode >=37 && charCode <= 47) {
                    btn.setAttribute('data-operation', button);
                } else if (charCode >=48 && charCode <= 57) {
                    btn.setAttribute('data-number', button);
                } else if ((charCode >=97 && charCode <= 122)
                   || (charCode >=65 && charCode <= 90)) {
                    btn.setAttribute('data-character', button);
                } else {
                    btn.setAttribute('data-delete', button);
                }
                btn.innerHTML = button;
                fragment.appendChild(btn);
            });
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <br /><br />

    <div id="fragment">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```